# "Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:" when updating controller dependencies

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm unable to get my project to run. It's fine until I...

1. Update my controller to include the `"$ionicPlatform, $cordovaToast, $cordovaLocalNotification"`

   ```
   .controller('MenuController', ['$scope', 'menuFactory', 'dishes', 'favoriteFactory', 'baseURL', '$ionicListDelegate', '$ionicPlatform', '$cordovaToast',  '$cordovaLocalNotification',
   function ($scope, menuFactory, dishes, favoriteFactory, baseURL, $ionicListDelegate, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaToast, $cordovaLocalNotification) {
   ```
2. I attempt to run my project and get

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $cordovaLocalNotificationProvider <- $cordovaLocalNotification <- MenuController

Then Angular doc and other posts I've seen suggest that that `$cordovaLocalNotification` has been omitted or misspelled in the dependency injection for this controller, but I'm sure they're the same.

Comment: Have you included the `ngCordova` module as a dependency in your module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure that you have included all the required JS files that is required to work $cordovaLocalNotification.

```
 <!-- ngCordova -->
<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>    

 var ctrls = angular.module('notiApp.controllers', ['ionic', 'ngCordova', 'ngCordova.plugins']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Bingo! Thanks for that. It was causing me grief...fyi. I had that script reference, but the order was wrong.

It WAS

```
<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ionic/js/angular/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>//THIS is the line
```

I change to the following and it resolved the issue.

```
<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>//THIS is the line
<script src="lib/ionic/js/angular/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
```